# Device not managed after upgrade to ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04, network-manager

Hi I recently upgraded to ubuntu 16 but I am now getting this:

[image]

which I don't understand because I only have two network devices and they are displayed below as working so what are the two unmanaged devices ?

this is the `ifconfig`, `/NetworkManager.conf` and `/etc/network/interfaces` contents

[image: ifconfig output]

```
NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

and

```
interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: Could you please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter you can either 1) select, copy & paste the terminal content or 2) [save it to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](//paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: There is a bug entry on Launchpad which describes the problem.
Please follow-up here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1458322

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those interfaces you see that are Not Managed come from the Virtual Network connections that have been setup by VMware Player.  Those are not controlled by the network manager that is why they show up as Unmanaged.

I just did a test on my system here, and they were not listed until I installed VMware Player on it.  Unfortunately, the keyboard I am using does not have PrntScrn on it so I cannot get a screenshot of my network connections.  But I can do the output of `nmcli`

Before installation:

```
:~$ nmcli d
DEVICE      TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION         
virbr0      bridge    connected  virbr0             
em1         ethernet  connected  Wired connection 1 
lo          loopback  unmanaged  --                 
virbr0-nic  tun       unmanaged  --
```

After installation:

```
:~$ nmcli d
DEVICE      TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION         
virbr0      bridge    connected  virbr0             
em1         ethernet  connected  Wired connection 1 
vmnet1      ethernet  unmanaged  --                 
vmnet8      ethernet  unmanaged  --                 
lo          loopback  unmanaged  --                 
virbr0-nic  tun       unmanaged  --                 


vmnet1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:01  
          inet addr:172.16.106.1  Bcast:172.16.106.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:61 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vmnet8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:08  
          inet addr:192.168.192.1  Bcast:192.168.192.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:61 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

After removal of VMware Player:

```
:~$ nmcli d
DEVICE      TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION         
virbr0      bridge    connected  virbr0             
em1         ethernet  connected  Wired connection 1 
lo          loopback  unmanaged  --                 
virbr0-nic  tun       unmanaged  --
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Terrance is right and those networks were created by a hypervisor such as Virtualbox or VMware Player. If you want to delete them you can first list them with `nmcli d`, and then execute with `sudo` the following ip command: `ip link delete <link-name>`